# How to use script tags in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am pretty new to React and I wanted to try incorporating some pure Javascript in my React component. I have an html file of the script tags that I want to use which works, but obviously in React it is a little more complicated then just adding some script tags. From what I have been reading, it seems like I need to learn JSX. Either which way, here are snippets of the html code I want to use and then the React component I am trying to use it in.

**HTML working code:**

```
<!-- grabs foo element (list itself) and sets a timeout of 1 second so we 
can toggle off the hidden text class -->

<script>
    const text = document.querySelector("#foo");
    setTimeout(() => {
        text.classList.toggle("hidden-text");
    }, 1000);
</script>
</body>
```

**React Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './HeroSec.css';``

/* Need to figure out how to use Javascript tags in React Component

const Hello = () => {
    return React.createElement(
        'script'
    )
}*/

function HeroSec(){
    return(
    <div className='hero-container'>
```

Comment: You should not need to do that. Is there a reason you are not adding and removing the class like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806073/adding-class-to-react-component-after-a-certain-amount-of-time/40806673 Trying to find a better example with useEffect

Comment: You can run vanilla JavaScript with React. In this case you may want to use it inside a `useEffect` hook that adds the timeout and clears it on unmount

Comment: thanks @epascarello and Dominik, this is already very helpful. do you guys have any examples with useEffect I can check out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The React Way

"I'm telling you Neo, when you use React properly, you won't have to."
see code live here https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-bohr-vzp2h?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import { useEffect, setState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShow(true);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My App</h1>
      {show ? <p>Hidden Text</p> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

So the idea is you focus on changing the logic of a single render pass rather than changing the particular DOM element. Focus on variable state and stop worrying about messing with DOM particulars. Calling `setShow(true)` tells react to re-render the scene automatically.

I personally love these quick setup projects at codesandbox.io and encourage you to give it a try and avoid having to worry about setup to get comfortable first.

Here's that example below and feel free to play with it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-bohr-vzp2h?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: This has definitely helped a lot, so thanks so much. I did try your example at codesandbox.io and I played around with it to try implementing what I specifically wanted to do. For the most part, it works pretty well, I just have a few follow up questions. 1) I notice the file is a .tsx, which I know is for JSX in React components. Do I need to install any package to actually imbed the JSX elements on my personal project? Also, this won't cause any errors considering this is the only component that would be a .tsx file in my React project, right?

Comment: @dom-nooch sorry its typescripted JSX. TypeScript is a life saver from a person who initially hated it... to loving it. You can just start another sandbox project and use non-typescript but I encourage you infinity to learn it. The code will  just work for JSX but you'll need to change the extension to "jsx".

Comment: Other than that, the only issue I seem to be having right now is making my specific animation occur every time I reload the page, which is not happening, it just happens the first time. Perhaps the problem is in my CSS, but to give you a general idea, I simply want the text to expand. Here is the updated test code of both the .tsx file and the .css file for you to get a better idea of what I am exactly trying to do. https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-edison-wppwb?file=/src/App.tsx https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-edison-wppwb?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: @dom-nooch so this might need to be another discussion... but I'll  leave it that you can change the className ```className={someStateVaar}``` then have css do its magic in terms of animations rather than showing and hiding in dom. Think state not DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow and to React! The great thing about React is that it's built on Javascript. This means you can definitely have pure javascript functions as part of the app. Here is a simple example app:

```
function App(){

  const SomeObject = {title:'Amazing',val:42};
  const SomeArray  = Object.entries(SomeObject);

  const SomeResult = <PassVal passed={SomeArray} />;

  // Javascript function
  function PassVal(props){
    const  value = props.passed[0][1];
    return value;
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <p>{SomeResult}</p>
    </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And here's some code that will load an external script:

```
function App() {
      const status = useScript(
        'https://pm28k14qlj.codesandbox.io/test-external-script.js'
      );
    
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
            Script status: <b>{status}</b>
          </div>
          {status === "ready" && (
            <div>
              Script function call response: <b>{TEST_SCRIPT.start()}</b>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    // Hook
    function useScript(src) {
      // Keep track of script status ("idle", "loading", "ready", "error")
      const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(src ? "loading" : "idle");
    
      React.useEffect(
        () => {
          // Allow falsy src value if waiting on other data needed for
          // constructing the script URL passed to this hook.
          if (!src) {
            setStatus("idle");
            return;
          }
    
          // Fetch existing script element by src
          // It may have been added by another intance of this hook
          let script = document.querySelector(`script[src="${src}"]`);
    
          if (!script) {
            // Create script
            script = document.createElement("script");
            script.src = src;
            script.async = true;
            script.setAttribute("data-status", "loading");
            // Add script to document body
            document.body.appendChild(script);
    
            // Store status in attribute on script
            // This can be read by other instances of this hook
            const setAttributeFromEvent = (event) => {
              script.setAttribute(
                "data-status",
                event.type === "load" ? "ready" : "error"
              );
            };
    
            script.addEventListener("load", setAttributeFromEvent);
            script.addEventListener("error", setAttributeFromEvent);
          } else {
            // Grab existing script status from attribute and set to state.
            setStatus(script.getAttribute("data-status"));
          }
    
          // Script event handler to update status in state
          // Note: Even if the script already exists we still need to add
          // event handlers to update the state for *this* hook instance.
          const setStateFromEvent = (event) => {
            setStatus(event.type === "load" ? "ready" : "error");
          };
    
          // Add event listeners
          script.addEventListener("load", setStateFromEvent);
          script.addEventListener("error", setStateFromEvent);
    
          // Remove event listeners on cleanup
          return () => {
            if (script) {
              script.removeEventListener("load", setStateFromEvent);
              script.removeEventListener("error", setStateFromEvent);
            }
          };
        },
        [src] // Only re-run effect if script src changes
      );
    
      return status;
    }

ReactDOM.render(
  <App  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```